# how to change the position of the cursor in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am on windows 10 and I prefer not to install a new module (standard library solutions are accepted). I want the text that the user enters to start at the end of the third line.

My code:

```
print(" Enter password to unlock the Safe .\n\n password : \n\n\t2 attempts remaining .")
# code to move the cursor to the end of " password : " goes here
x = input()
```

output:

[image]

wanted output:

[image]

Also ANSI escape sequences don't seem to work without colorama(which unfortunately is an external module).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows 10 you can use ANSI escape sequences as found in [Console Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences).

Before using them you need `subprocess.run('', shell=True)` (prior to Python 3.5, use `subprocess.call`). These sequences make possible what you are looking for.

Caution: Also original Microsoft, the documentation of *Erase in Display* and *Erase in Line* is partly faulty. The  parameters *1* and *2* are reversed.

This should work (although, actually entering the password seems to destroy the layout):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run('', shell=True)
print(' enter password : \0337', end='')
print('\n\n\t2 attempts remaining .\0338', end='')
x = input()
```

Comment: Could you give an example like an implementation of that on the code i posted?

Comment: @nickven To use Warner's code you need to import the subprocess module. I can't test it myself, though, because I don't run Windows.

Comment: yeah now it works, thanks a lot. I must have typed it wrong the first time :)

Comment: Why `subprocess.run("")`? What kind of sorcery is this?

Answer (score -1):

With Python 3 use;

```
print("...", end="")
```

Comment: i've tried that, it makes the cursor go at the end of the last line

Comment: Try this:
import sys
sys.stdout.write("enter: ")

Comment: You want to go first line. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27612545/how-to-change-the-location-of-the-pointer-in-python