# How can move terminal cursor in Python?

Tags: python, tetris

I'm making Tetris game with Python in Linux, but I can't move terminal cursor to what I want to position

How can move cursor position?? in Python

Comment: You need to post your code and specify which part of your code is not working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the location of the pointer in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27612545/how-to-change-the-location-of-the-pointer-in-python)

Comment: this post does not lack details or clarity. it is clear what OP wants. It should instead be closed as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27612545/how-to-change-the-location-of-the-pointer-in-python/27612978#27612978

Comment: @Neuron: Generally on Stack Overflow we tend to not reopen a question just for close it with another reason. You could leave a comment about what close reason seems to be better in your opinion, but reopening a question mostly wastes a time and a gives a risk to leave a question opened. You may find discussions on this topic on meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262761/should-we-allow-voting-to-change-the-close-vote-reason-of-a-question

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks for the info. I retracted my vote

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This seems like a duplicate, however referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27612978/8859876), it appears that you should be using the colorama module to make this task easier and after doing so you should be able to move your cursor around by simply using

```py
def move (y, x):
    print("\033[%d;%dH" % (y, x))
```