# Formatting input prompt in python

Tags: python

Is there a way to format the input field above the options?

Currently,

```
abc = input('choose an option: \n 1 \n 2 \n')
```

results in:

```
choose an option:
1
2
X
```

with X being where the input will appear. Is there any way to make it like this:

```
choose an option: X
1
2
```

so that the input appears in the first line of the prompt?

Comment: If your terminal can interpret "move cursor up, move cursor right" *control characters*, then you can output those.

Comment: Alternatively, there's TUI libraries which you can consider.

Comment: Check if this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27612545/how-to-change-the-location-of-the-pointer-in-python/27612978#27612978

Comment: seems like too complex an implementation for my project if it were to work anyway