# Python overwrite a line with another specified line

Tags: python, ansi-escape

How can I overwrite already printed text to STDOUT with an arbitrary string? For example:

```py
print("Overwrite this line")
print("I do not want to overwrite any line")
print("I want to overwrite the first line")
```

How can I overwrite the **first** print statement with the **third** print statement? The second line should remain as it is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the location of the pointer in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27612545/how-to-change-the-location-of-the-pointer-in-python)

Comment: For Linux, the best option is probably [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/curses.html#curses-programming-with-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ANSI escape sequences](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html), as long as your terminal supports them (this is the case on Linux, I'm not sure about Windows)

In particular, the interesting ones for this problem are:

- `\033[<N>A` - Move the cursor up N lines
- `\033[<N>B` - Move the cursor down N lines

You can print the first two lines normally, then for the third one move up 2 lines, print it (this will print a newline and move the cursor to the second line), move down 1 line and continue with your code. I interted some delays in the code so that the effect is visible:

```
print("Overwrite this line")
time.sleep(1)
print("I do not want to overwrite any line")
time.sleep(1)
print("\033[2AI want to overwrite the first line\033[1B")
```

Comment: `cmd.exe` and `wt.exe`, the two default command-line applications (for Windows) support this. But first, `os.system('')` must be used in order for them to work.

Answer (score -1):

You must use conditional statements. If statement for example:

```py
choice = input('what do you want to display? 1 or 2')

if choice == '1' then:
    print('I want to overwrite the first line')
else:
    print('I do not want to overwrite any line')
```

Does this answer your question? If not, please elaborate.

Comment: This has no element of overwriting previous printed lines. It does not answer the question

Answer (score -2):

Use `escape sequence \r` for this purpose. And for wait use `time.sleep`

```
import time

print("Overwrite this line", end="")
time.sleep(10)
print("\rI want to overwrite the first line")
print("I do not want to overwrite any line")
```

For more precise result `wait for key press`. and **check out this code:**

```
import msvcrt as m
def wait():
    m.getch()

print("Overwrite this line", end="")
wait()
print("\rI want to overwrite the first line")
print("I do not want to overwrite any line")
```

Comment: third line didn't overwrite first line

Comment: Well, you changed the meaning of the lines to make it look like it works... The second line says *"I __do not__ want to overwrite any line"* and the third one says *"I __want__ to overwrite the first line"*. Your code is doing the opposite

Comment: @AaravPrasad can i answer, using logic `first clear then reprint it`